# log4j2 logs are not being written into file

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I'm using log4j2 and I have the following log4j2.xml file:

**log4j2.xml Configuration File(below):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="PropertiesConfig">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="baseDir">log/</Property>
        <Property name="logName">report</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" 
                 target="SYSTEM_OUT"
                 immediateFlush="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%highlight{%-5level] %d %c{1}.%M() - %msg%n}" />
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" 
                     fileName="${baseDir}${logName}.log"
                     filePattern="${baseDir}${logName}_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
                     immediateFlush="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d %c{1}.%M() - %msg%n" />
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="info" />    
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" level="warn" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

My project is a Web Application using Java. If I use the log system from a Serlvet, like:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;

public class MySevlet {
   private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(MyServlet.class);

   protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      LOGGER.warn("hello?");
      LOGGER.error("hello?");
      //...more stuff here...
   }
   //...more stuff here...
}
```

**Project folder structure (below):**

[image]

The problem I have is I can see the console logs, but no file is written, so Rolling file appender doesn't work.

If I run a local program (not using Servlets), both console and rolling file appender works.

Any idea why is this happening?

Thank you!

PS: I'm using Netbeans 8.2 + Tomcat 8.0

Comment: Check your imports. Log4j2 uses org.apache.logging.log4j artifacts and you're using wrong org.apache.log4j artifacts from older logger version.

Comment: Thanks @dmitriy-yankin . I've changed that, but the problem continues. Moreover, now, the local program doesn't log inside the file (just create the file, but void) :(

Comment: Update: I've found where's the problem. In the xml configuration file, I've written the full path to the file ("baseDir" property) and it works. So... how could I write the relative path for the Web version?